# Count of CIDRs exceeds max limit: 0 in Oracle Cloud

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am always getting some wired error during the creation of VCN.

```
Count of CIDRs exceeds max limit: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have exceeded your service quota limit for the VCN, you can refer this for details on how to request for the quota limit increase : https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/General/Concepts/servicelimits.htm#Requesti
you can even try to create the VCN using CLI : [https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/oci-cli/2.16.0/oci_cli_docs/cmdref/network/vcn/create.html[enter](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/oci-cli/2.16.0/oci_cli_docs/cmdref/network/vcn/create.html%5Benter) link description here][2](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/oci-cli/2.16.0/oci_cli_docs/cmdref/network/vcn/create.html)

Thanks,
Hemanth.

Answer (score 1):

I used vcn wizard and it resolved. Configure VCN and Subnets VCN CIDR BLOCK xx.0.xx.0/yy If you plan to peer this VCN with another VCN, the VCNs must not have overlapping CIDRs. Learn more. PUBLIC SUBNET CIDR BLOCK xx.0.0.0/zz The subnet CIDR blocks must not overlap. PRIVATE SUBNET CIDR BLOCK x.0.xx.0/zz The subnet CIDR blocks must not overlap. –

Hint: that quota limit is coming from the compartment.